# What should i use to solve this multithreading issue in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am very new to Thread in java. In my application, i will have a single thread(producer) which will do some processing from the input data and keep adding String objects into a data structure named A(which i dk what to use) and concurrently, multiple consumer thread taking out what is in A. Each consumer thread will take out one object at a time, processing it and put into another data structure named B. I have read up about thread and threadsafe  data structure but i have no idea which is ideal for my case. I am advised not to use blocking data structure such as BlockingQueue but was not explained well on the reason. Can someone kindly explain to me why and recommend me suitable data structure for A and B?

I am thinking to use LinkedList for A and Treeset for B. Am i on the right track?

Comment: It sounds like a BlockingQueue would be perfect for your purposes. I assume you are doing this for a class, and your teacher probably wants you to build your own version of a BlockQueue ADT. If you are confused as to how to do this, you should probably ask your teacher for further help

Comment: Do you mind explaining to me how does the BlockingQueue works when it comes to multiple thread taking objects out from A? Oh btw it is not a class assignment and it is not aim to build my own version of BlockQueue. It is needed in one of the functions in my internship work.

Comment: The generic name for a data structure that a producer can put objects into, and a consumer can pull objects from is _pool_.  Queues and stacks and heaps and sets and multisets and ... are all different kinds of pool that have different rules about what can go in to the pool and different rules about the order in which things come out.  When they aren't being used for communication between threads, the same data structues are generically known as _containers_ or _collections_.

Comment: please kindly look at my new update of my draft implementation... does it looks ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BlockingQueue` is the go-to tool for implementing the producer-consumer pattern.  See *[Java Concurrency in Practice](http://amzn.to/1jyE5Kx)*, chapter 5, for more detail.

Starting non-thread-safe data structures like `LinkedList` and `TreeSet` is definitely the wrong track here.  I don't know why your colleague suggested avoiding blocking, but if you try to do so, you will almost certainly end up reinventing blocking data structures along the way, and probably badly.

Until you are an expert, stick to the standard path...

Comment: so in the scenario of blocking queue with multiple consumer, so does the consumers takes stuff from A in parallel?

Comment: The consumers can take from a blocking queue "in parallel."  (I would say "asynchronously";  parallelism is slightly different.)  You have to set up the consumers properly of course.  Each in it's own thread, and no other locks which cause them to become serial.

Comment: hi i will try to implement my workerthread now, and really would like to show you for validation but i do not know how to link u up....how can i do so? creating another qns?

Answer (score 1):

LinkedList is not thread safe, you should implement some locking logic yourself. The same applies to TreeSet. Therefore, they are not the best way to go.

BlockingQueue sounds like a good option since it provides blocking operations. E.g. the consumers can block waiting for an element to become available (get added to queue by the producer). Also, the producer will get blocked if the queue is full, until a consumer removes an element from the queue for processing.

ConcurrentLinkedQueue is thread safe as well. But it does not provide the blocking operations that I mentioned above (I think you will need those).

I'd suggest you go for BlockingQueue.

Comment: thanks, as u mentioned, BlockingQueue provides blocking operations... can u elaborate more on it. So it will only block when A is empty and it will unblock itself when an element comes in? And if in the cases of many thread waiting to take out stuff how does blocking queue works?

Comment: Yes,assume that the queue is empty.The consumer thread calls queue.take() and gets blocked.As soon as an element gets added to the queue by the producer thread, the consumer thread gets unblocked in order to process the item. As mentioned on the docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) you can have multiple producer/consumer threads. The idea remains the same. One of the consumer threads will pick up the item of the queue and process it (the rest will remain blocked). Also check: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html

Comment: very gd tutorial link thanks alot. Btw last qns, so do i have to do notify(), to let the thread that is blocked due to empty to wake and start taking?

Comment: No, you don't have to worry about "low-level" synchronization calls such as wait/notify[All]. You just insert/remove elements from the queue and let the BlockingQueue implementation take care of blocking/unblocking threads.

Comment: please kindly look at my new update of my draft implementation... does it looks ok?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of you problem.

1. 'A' (Single instance) gets data from some where , does some processing on data post that data into some "Data Structure".
2. Multiple instances of B read from this data structure and does the processing.

This is a pattern --> Its know as "Pipe and Filter" Pattern and it is most often used where there is a step wise processing of data. output of one process acts as input of another. In this case --> A , B acts as a filter and the data structure is the pipe. you need to use a queue data structure in this case :
1. The queue should be thread safe
2. It should be of fixed size because if Producer is faster than consumer you might run out of all memory and get an exception.
3. if the queue is full and A tries to put data into it , it should not throw exception but in form A accordingly.

Considering all the above cases you should use "LinkedBlockingQueue"

Comment: wow totally bulls eye for all the assumption. Yes i will be implementing LinkedBlockingQueue with multithreading, almost done... please kindly keep a look out in my next post so i can improve to learn and also to impress my supervisor. haha. Really appreciate insights and comments from experts like you guys.

Comment: please kindly look at my new update of my draft implementation... does it looks ok?